# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm having an issue and I have no idea why this is happening and how to fix it. I'm working on developing a Videogame with python and pygame and I'm getting this error:

```
 File "/home/matt/Smoking-Games/sg-project00/project00/GameModel.py", line 15, in Update 
   self.imageDef=self.values[2]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The code:

```
import pygame,components
from pygame.locals import *

class Player(components.Entity):

    def __init__(self,images):
        components.Entity.__init__(self,images)
        self.values=[]

    def Update(self,events,background):
        move=components.MoveFunctions()
        self.values=move.CompleteMove(events)
        self.imageDef=self.values[2]
        self.isMoving=self.values[3]

    def Animation(self,time):
        if(self.isMoving and time==1):
            self.pos+=1
            if (self.pos>(len(self.anim[self.imageDef])-1)):
                self.pos=0
        self.image=self.anim[self.imageDef][self.pos]
```

Can you explain to me what that error means and why it is happening so I can fix it?

Comment: Somehow `self.values` is set to None.  What is `move.CompleteMove` supposed to do?  What value does it return?

Comment: Also note that any function which doesn't have a return statement will return `None`, so check carefully for this case.

Answer (score 27):

BrenBarn is correct. The error means you tried to do something like `None[5]`. In the backtrace, it says `self.imageDef=self.values[2]`, which means that your `self.values` is `None`.

You should go through all the functions that update `self.values` and make sure you account for all the corner cases.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping me I could fix the issue, there was an indentation error on the return statement so it was returning None lol

Answer (score 8):

`move.CompleteMove()` does not return a value (perhaps it just prints something). Any method that does not return a value returns `None`, and you have assigned `None` to `self.values`.

Here is an example of this:

```
>>> def hello(x):
...    print x*2
...
>>> hello('world')
worldworld
>>> y = hello('world')
worldworld
>>> y
>>>
```

You'll note `y` doesn't print anything, because its `None` (the only value that doesn't print anything on the interactive prompt).

Answer (score 1):

The function `move.CompleteMove(events)` that you use within your class probably doesn't contain a `return` statement. So nothing is returned to `self.values` (==> None). Use `return` in `move.CompleteMove(events)` to return whatever you want to store in `self.values` and it should work. Hope this helps.