# Python_TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, types

```
def solve(v,q):
  #print "reach solve"
  if isInside(v,left(q)) == True:
    out = solving(v,q)
  elif isInside(v, right(q)) == True:
    reverse = q[::-1]
    #reverse = [right(q) + '=' + left(q)]
    out = solving(v,reverse)
  #if type(out[0]) == types.ListType:
  print out[0]
  if out[0] == "x":
    pass
  else:
    out = solving(v,out)
  return out
```

I receive the following message when I try to run the program. out[0] should be a string of "x". I have several successful test case, but several of them fail at this point.

Could any one please explain to me what potentially happen here. Thank you!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lab1.py", line 147, in <module>
    main()
  File "lab1.py", line 131, in main
    print solve('x', [['a', '-', 'x'], '=', 'c'])  #  ['x', '=', ['a', '-', 'c']]
  File "lab1.py", line 109, in solve
    print out[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: It seems like your 'solving' method is returning None. So, your out variable is holding None and not a list.

Comment: post the whole code please. or you can try debug by yourself, with eclipse or pycharm

Answer (score 0):

`out` is defined in your `if` statements and may never get assigned if the condition is not True.  Before the first `if` statement, add `out[0] = None`.

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

means that you are trying to use a null ('NoneType') reference in an illegal way. [Here's another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907949/typeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-getitem).

The line `print out[0]` references the first element of `out`, so `out` needs to be an iterable, i.e. have ordered elements like a list. Since null isn't iterable, the runtime doesn't know how to get its first element and instead throws that error.

You need to figure out how `out` is getting assigned to null. There are two possibilities that I can see:

1. `out` is getting assigned to null because your `solving` function is returning null. This is because `out` may be assigned the return value of `solving`, e.g. on the line `out = solving(v,q)`. You'd have to post the `solving` function for us to say anything more specific about this.
2. If `out` is *not a local variable*, i.e. you have initialized it elsewhere in the code, then it could have been initialized to null and never reassigned. As other answers have pointed out, your if/elif structure doesn't guarantee that `out` gets assigned in that function. This scenario would look something like:

.

```
out = null # out is set to null

def solve(v,q):
  if isInside(v,left(q)) == True: # say isInside(v,left(q)) is False
    out = solving(v,q)
  elif isInside(v, right(q)) == True: # say isInside(v, right(q)) is False
    reverse = q[::-1]
    out = solving(v,reverse)
  # both the if and elif were false, so out was never reassigned 
  # this means out is still null
  print out[0] # error
  ...
```